# SlickGrid cannot delete added rows, but only existing ones. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

Here is my code for adding a row:

```
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    var item = args.item;
    id=id+1;
    item["id"] = "id_"+id;
    grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
    data.push(item);
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.endUpdate();
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});
```

And here is my code for deleting a row:

```
if ((event.which == 46)) {
    $(".slick-cell.selected").parent().each(function() {
        var item = dataView.getItem($(this).attr("row"));
        var rowid = item.id;
        dataView.deleteItem(rowid);
        grid.invalidate();
        grid.render();
    });
}
```

This works for already existing rows but not for the added ones. for some reasons THE `item` variable is undefined for new rows. What am I doing wrong?

**Edited** 
Thanks, Tin! So I`ve got a solution :

```
      grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) {
        var item = args.item;
        id=id+1;
        item["id"] = "id_"+id;
        data.push(item);
        dataView.beginUpdate();
        dataView.setItems(data);
        dataView.endUpdate();
      });
```

.

```
       if ((event.which == 46)){
            var rows = grid.getSelectedRows();
            for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
                var item = dataView.getItem(rows[i]);
                var rowid = item.id;
                dataView.deleteItem(rowid);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sidenote: It looks like your code contains a surplus `}` bracket.

Comment: edited code. My mistake. In my code there is no such mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing a lot of things in your code that don't quite make sense to me:

In your onAddNewRow handler, you are:

1. Invalidating the row being added.  Why?  You don't need to do that.
2. You update the "data" array directly but then do a no-op call on the "dataView".  What are you using as a data source - data or dataView?
3. You don't need to tell the grid to updateRowCount() or render().

In your delete handler:

1. DO NOT access SlickGrid DOM directly (i.e. $(".slick-cell.selected"))!  Use grid.getSelectedRows() instead.
2. If you are using "dataView" as your data source, you should already have events wired up to listen to DataView changes and update the grid as needed.  Calls to grid.invalidate() and grid.render() are not needed.